# Offline Storage Vs Service Worker for a Progressive Web App

Tags: indexeddb, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

My app saves the data (product catalog) in the Offline storage [IndexedDB](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa) and read it from there whenever necessary. Instead of using custom JavaScript to save and retrieve the data from the IndexedDB, can I use [Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/lifecycle) to get the same results?

Comment: It'd probably be helpful to provide a bit more context around what you're trying to achieve. ServiceWorkers have access to IndexedDB, so without knowing too much about what you're trying to achieve, writing a ServiceWorker that uses IndexedDB in a similar fashion to how you currently are should be relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Service Workers are developed using "custom" JavaScript, so there would be no difference for your code.

But you could keep your current JavaScript, and cache it with a Service Worker for offline.